# multiprocessing and modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to use `multiprocessing` to call derived class member function defined in a different module. There seem to be several questions dealing with calling class methods from the same module, but none from different modules. For example, if I have the following structure:

```
main.py
multi/
    __init__.py (empty)
    base.py
    derived.py
```

**main.py**

```
from multi.derived import derived
from multi.base import base

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base().multiFunction()
    derived().multiFunction()
```

**base.py**

```
import multiprocessing;

# The following two functions wrap calling a class method
def wrapPoolMapArgs(classInstance, functionName, argumentLists):
    className = classInstance.__class__.__name__
    return zip([className] * len(argumentLists), [functionName] * len(argumentLists), [classInstance] * len(argumentLists), argumentLists)

def executeWrappedPoolMap(args, **kwargs):
    classType = eval(args[0])
    funcType = getattr(classType, args[1])
    funcType(args[2], args[3:], **kwargs)

class base:
    def multiFunction(self):
        mppool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        mppool.map(executeWrappedPoolMap, wrapPoolMapArgs(self, 'method', range(3)))

    def method(self,args):
        print "base.method: " + args.__str__()
```

**derived.py**

```
from base import base

class derived(base):
    def method(self,args):
        print "derived.method: " + args.__str__()
```

**Output**

```
base.method: (0,)
base.method: (1,)
base.method: (2,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\temp\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    derived().multiFunction()
  File "e:\temp\multi\base.py", line 15, in multiFunction
    mppool.map(executeWrappedPoolMap, wrapPoolMapArgs(self, 'method', range(3)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'derived' is not defined
```

I have tried fully qualifying the class name in the `wrapPoolMethodArgs` method, but that just gives the same error, saying `multi` is not defined.

Is there someway to achieve this, or must I restructure to have all classes in the same package if I want to use `multiprocessing` with inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by the ridiculous `eval` based approach to dynamically invoking specific code.

In `executeWrappedPoolMap` (in `base.py`), you convert a `str` name of a class to the `class` itself with `classType = eval(args[0])`. But `eval` is executed in the scope of `executeWrappedPoolMap`, which is in `base.py`, and can't find `derived` (because the name doesn't exist in `base.py`).

Stop passing the name, and pass the `class` object itself, passing `classInstance.__class__` instead of `classInstance.__class__.__name__`; `multiprocessing` will pickle it for you, and you can use it directly on the other end, instead of using `eval` (which is nearly always wrong; it's code smell of the strongest sort).

BTW, the reason the traceback isn't super helpful is that the exception is raised in the worker, caught, `pickle`-ed, and sent back to the main process and re-`raise`-ed. The traceback you see is from that re-`raise`, not where the `NameError` actually occurred (which was in the `eval` line).

Comment: I was originally having problems with the instance pickling, which is why I changed it to an eval of the name instead - but obviously that isn't required. Just passing the instance as you suggest works - thanks.